# Failure to use udev rule to change smart card device ownership in Xen/QubesOs VM

Tags: smartcard, gnupg, xen, udev, qubes-os

In a Xen VM (within QubesOS) , I can see my handed-through USB smart card reader like this:

```
Prompt> lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04e6:5116 SCM Microsystems, Inc. SCR331-LC1 / SCR3310 SmartCard Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
...
```

Looking deeper with `udevadm` yields:

```
Prompt> udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/bus/usb/002/002)
looking at device '/devices/platform/vhci_hcd/usb2/2-1':
  KERNEL=="2-1"
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb"
  DRIVER=="usb"
  ATTR{authorized}=="1"
  ATTR{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
  ATTR{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
  ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="00"
  ATTR{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
  ATTR{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
  ATTR{bMaxPacketSize0}=="32"
  ATTR{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
  ATTR{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
  ATTR{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
  ATTR{bcdDevice}=="0204"
  ATTR{bmAttributes}=="a0"
  ATTR{busnum}=="2"
  ATTR{configuration}=="CCID Class"
  ATTR{devnum}=="2"
  ATTR{devpath}=="1"
  ATTR{idProduct}=="5116"
  ATTR{idVendor}=="04e6"
  ATTR{ltm_capable}=="no"
  ATTR{manufacturer}=="SCM Microsystems Inc."
  ATTR{maxchild}=="0"
  ATTR{product}=="SCR3310 v2.0 USB SC Reader"
  ATTR{quirks}=="0x0"
  ATTR{removable}=="unknown"
  ATTR{speed}=="12"
  ATTR{urbnum}=="14"
  ATTR{version}==" 2.00"

looking at parent device '/devices/platform/vhci_hcd/usb2':
  KERNELS=="usb2"
  SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
  DRIVERS=="usb"
...
```

Despite the fact that the permissions are set as follows:

```
Prompt> ls -la /dev/bus/usb/002/002
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 129 May  3 23:01 /dev/bus/usb/002/002
```

the result of a call to `gpg2 --card-status` works as `root`, but as a normal user yields a `Card error`.
I try to remedy this with the following `udev` rule (`/etc/udev/rules.d/51-SCR3310.rules`):

```
KERNEL=="usb*", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5116", MODE="0660", GROUP="user"
```

but no matter what I do, I cannot get a normal user to have access to the reader through `gpg2`.

Where am I screwing this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much googling (startpaging, that is), I finally found my answer [here](https://gist.github.com/ageis/5b095b50b9ae6b0aa9bf).

On top of needing a `/etc/udev/rules.d/71-gpg-ccid.rules` file with the following content to make udev allow my user's group (`user`) access to the device (taken from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG))

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="04e6", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="5116", MODE="660", GROUP="user"
```

I was hit by interference of `gnome-keyring` with `gpg-agent` and adding

```
Hidden=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
```

to the ends of `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop` and `gnome-keyring-gpg.desktop` mart smartcard access as a normal user work.